# Creating a sub-subdomain on AWS Route 53

Tags: dns, subdomain, amazon-route53

I'm trying to set up a a domain for our staging environment which mirrors the domain structure of our production environment. For example:

```
puppet.example.com         # production
puppet.staging.example.com # staging
```

I have a hosted zone for `example.com` where I have the puppet subdomain working fine. I've also created a hosted zone for `staging.example.com` and created a record for the puppet subdomain within that, but I can't get it working.

When I use `nslookup` on `puppet.staging.example.com` the IP address that appears isn't the address I've configured on Route 53.

Do I need to do something different when setting up a hosted zone for a sub domain?

Answer (score 13):

To host both `puppet.example.com` and `puppet.staging.example.com` using AWS Route53, you would only need to create **one** hosted zone:

```
example.com
```

Once you create the hosted-zone, you would create two "record sets", one for each sub-domain. Since you want the names to be equivalent, their type and value should match (i.e., the `A` record or `CNAME` record should be the same).

You don't need to do anything special about "sub-subdomains," just include a dot (`.`) in the name. For example:

```
Name            Type    Value
puppet          A       1.2.3.4
puppet.staging  A       1.2.3.4
```

Answer (score -2):

To support both example.com and subdomains with .(dot) included, you need to use wildcard for the hosted zone name as follows.

```
*.example.com
```

For more information read the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/DomainNameFormat.html) on domain name format. Also note that, when mapping the subdomain with wildcard following rules needs to be met.

> The `*` must replace the leftmost label in a domain name, for example,
>   `*.example.com`. It can't replace any of the middle labels, for example, `marketing.*.example.com`.
>
> The `*` must replace the entire label. For example, you can't specify
>   `*prod.example.com` or `prod*.example.com`.

Comment: Based on the documentation provided you **can't** start a hosted-zone with an asterisk (and you shouldn't need to).

Comment: To clarify, the docs say that for a `Hosted Zone` you can't use a wildcard, but for a `Record` on a hosted zone you can. Also says the asterisk *must* be at the beginning like this answer talks about